# Solve, without using automation the following equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{1}{1}\left(\frac{x}{2008}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{2008}+\frac{2}{3}\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x}{2008}+\frac{3}{4}\right)+\cdots+\frac{1}{2008}\left(\frac{x}{2008}+\frac{2008}{2009}\right)=\frac{x}{2009}$$

$x$ being a real number. Give a closed form of $x$.

P.S. Do not ask me to add more information, I do not want to influence your answer, I have an answer, I would like to make comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the slickest way, but was my first thought, and therefore the quickest first up.

Let $H=1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\dots +\frac 1{2008}$, then we can rewrite the equation as$$\frac {Hx}{2008}+H-1+\frac 1{2009}=\frac x{2009}$$ or (clearing fractions, and noting $-1+\frac 1{2009}=-\frac {2008}{2009})$ $$2009Hx+2009\cdot 2008H-2008^2 =2008x$$ or $$x(2009H-2008)=-2008(2009H-2008)$$ whence $x=-2008$

Comment: Okay, I've made a mistake due to my chaotic handwriting(i.e. turned a product into a sum). Thanks!